# Hamburger sidebar - Hide outside click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide this left sidebar when someone click outside.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gapvwso3/)

I tried adding this

```
$('.nav').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

and tried to add `.stopPropagation();` to body area click but not working. Am I using this wrong way?

Comment: Hey, In your code you aren't actually using jQuery right? ':D

Comment: Is there any other use of `hamburger.nav.addEventListener('click', function(e) {hamburger.doToggle(e); })` code? If you remove this listener, this seems work as you expected.

Comment: @JitendraG2 Does it? If I click in the blue area it doesn't close.

Comment: @JitendraG2 Not working at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this fiddle I made: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ly2cj9na/2/). I wrapped your menu with additional div and check if user clicked on that div or outside. Then I also check if menu is collapsed or not.

```
  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   var element = document.querySelector('.menu');
   if (e.target !== element && !element.contains(e.target) 
       && hamburger.nav.classList.contains('expanded')) {
         hamburger.doToggle(e);
       }
   });
```

Comment: Working fine. Thanks mn!